# How to solve the error of 'No features contain non-null values of "system:time_start".' in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, time-series

I'm trying to create a time series chart for SST and NDCI retrieving from Modis and Sentinel2 respectively by using the below code, but I get an error of `No features contain non-null values of "system:time_start"`. How can I solve this problem?

```
var geometry = 
    /* color: #d63000 */
    /* shown: false */
    /* displayProperties: [
      {
        "type": "rectangle"
      }
    ] */
    ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[99.45287204043024, 13.987093052423877],
          [99.45287204043024, 11.662710322951911],
          [101.56224704043024, 11.662710322951911],
          [101.56224704043024, 13.987093052423877]]], null, false);
var sentinel2 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2");
var modis = ee.ImageCollection('NASA/OCEANDATA/MODIS-Aqua/L3SMI');

var ndci_viz = {
  bands: "NDCI",
  min:-1,
  max:1,
  palette: ['#22F7D4','#22D4F7','#70AFFF','#8761FF ','#F529FE']
};

var sst_viz = {
  bands: 'sst',
  min:10,
  max:50,
  palette: ['#396CFA','#4EE5F7','#EF6305','#E20806']
};

var S22017 = sentinel2.filterBounds(geometry)
               .filterDate('2017-01-01', '2017-12-31')
               .sort('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', false)
               .map(function (image){
                 return image.addBands(image.metadata('system:time_start'));
               })
               .mosaic()
               .clip(geometry); 

var S2water = s2_ndwi(S22017);
var ndci17 = ndci_algorithm(S2water);
Map.addLayer(ndci17.select('NDCI'), ndci_viz,"NDCI in 2017");

var modis2017 = modis.filterBounds(geometry)
               .filterDate('2017-01-01', '2017-12-31').select('sst')
               .mean()
               .clip(geometry);

Map.addLayer(modis2017, sst_viz, 'SST in 2017'); 



function s2_ndwi(img){
  //water mask
  var ndwi = img.normalizedDifference(['B3', 'B8']).rename('NDWI');
  return img.addBands(ndwi)
  .updateMask(ndwi.gt(0));
}

function ndci_algorithm(image){
  var ndci = image.expression(
    '((B5*sf) - (B4*sf))/((B5*sf) + (B4*sf))', {
      'B4': image.select('B4'),
      'B5': image.select('B5'),
      'sf': 0.0001
      
    }).rename('NDCI');
  return(ndci.rename('NDCI').set('system:time_start', image.get('system:time_start'))
  .set('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', image.get('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE')));
}

var sstchart = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion({
  imageCollection: modis2017.select('sst'), 
  regions: geometry,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  scale: 50,
})
.setChartType('LineChart')
.setOptions({
      lineWidth: 1,
      pointSize: 3,
      title: 'SST Time Series',
      interpolateNulls: true,
      vAxis: {title: 'SST',titleTextStyle: {italic: false, bold: true}},
      hAxis: {title: 'Date',titleTextStyle: {italic: false, bold: true}},
    });
print('SST in 2017', sstchart);

var ndciChart = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion({
  imageCollection: ndci17.select('NDCI'), 
  regions: geometry,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  scale: 10,
})
.setChartType('LineChart')
.setOptions({
      lineWidth: 1,
      pointSize: 3,
      title: 'NDCI Time Series',
      interpolateNulls: true,
      vAxis: {title: 'SST',titleTextStyle: {italic: false, bold: true}},
      hAxis: {title: 'Date',titleTextStyle: {italic: false, bold: true}},
    });
print('NDCI in 2017', ndciChart);
```

Answer (score 0):

In both of your mapped functions you need to copy the date onto your newly created image, using copyProperties.